# Add user to AD group depening on location and if they are not added to an ad group name like

Tags: powershell

Fairly new and as of next month I will be on a PowerShell training course, but management needs this now, so any help will be helpful!

The script needs to be run every hour and needs to look though every user in AD and needs to do the following.

1. Check if the account is enabled, if so continue to step 2.
2. Check they are not already a part of an AD group named like “HP” if so do 
   nothing. If they are not part of an ad group with a name like “HP” continue to step 3.
3. Get a list of the user’s city.
4. If user’s city matches ‘London’ add to AD group called “HP EU”
5. If user’s city matches ‘Hong Kong’ add to AD group called “HP Asia”
6. If user’s city matches ‘New York add to AD group called “HP America”

END

What i have is this but it is not working

It seems to not like the switch stament

```
    Get-ADGroup -filter {name -like"HP*"} 
$Users = get-aduser -Identity testuser -properties City,MemberOf | where{$_.city -ne $Null}
Foreach($user in $Users){
    IF(-not($user.memberof -notlike "HP*")
            $group = Switch ($User.city){
            "London" {"HP EU"}
            "Hong Kong" {"HP Asia"}
            "New York" {"HP US"}
                    }
        $groupDN = (get-adgroup $group).DistinguishedName
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupDN -Members $user 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have provided you code snippets on how to fetch the required details. However, I would not like to give the complete script, as that would discourage you to learn Powershell. I do not want to hold you back. Please build your script using the below logic as a baseline. :)

use "Get-Command -noun AD*" if you want to know more cmdlets about Active Directory.

```
Check if user account is enabled/disabled:
------------------------------------------
$UserName = “UserName”
$searcher = new-object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher([ADSI]””)
$searcher.filter = “(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName= $UserName))”
$founduser = $searcher.findOne()
$founduser.Properties.useraccountcontrol
$value = $founduser.Properties.useraccountcontrol
if ($Value -eq 514)
 {
 Write-Output “Account is disabled”
 }

if ($Value -eq 512)
 {
 Write-Output “Account is Enabled”
 }



Check if user belongs to group:
------------------------------
$user = "TestUser"
$group = "Domain Admins"
$members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Recursive | Select -ExpandProperty Name

If ($members -contains $user) {
      Write-Host "$user exists in the group"
 } Else {
        Write-Host "$user not exists in the group"
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help i have updated my question with what i have done, but it still doesnt seem to like it. any ideas?